# Use multiple presenters for the same Activity

Tags: android, mvp, presenter

I'm trying to use MVP in my new project. I have a **Single Activity and multiple presenters** that can be associated with it.

- Presenter1 - Load Activity Data
- Presenter2 - Load User data - that can be used in multiple Activities (So this presenter will be used in multiple activities
- Presenter3 - User Actions - This can also be used in more than one Activities.

For now, I have used all the 3 presenters for one Activity. Is there anything I can do to use only single presenter to access all the methods for the 3 presenters? Searched a lot, but could not find any relevant reference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is the answer you're looking for but you could try an architecture more like [clean architecture](https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html) and isolate the logic of each of your use cases in an interactor and then inject your three interactors in one unic presenter for your activity.

And later, when you'll need to re-use that logic you will have a LoadUserInteractor and a UserActionInteractor to inject into that new presenter.

If you do not want to create interactors in your architecture you could create an abstract present who have the methods for load user data and user actions and let your activity presenter extends it with the load activity data but I'm not sure it will be long before it cause you some maintenance problems.